# Where does all the chakra of Edo Tensei shinobi come from?

Tags: naruto

Where does all the chakra needed for the reanimated shinobi come from? It certainly cannot come from the caster, because the scale of the chakra being used for techniques is huge. In Kabuto's case, he was controlling several Edo Tensei shinobi at once. So all the chakra they were using couldn't possibly be coming from him.

Also, when Madara **broke** the Edo Tensei's [contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdCBR.png), he mentioned about "limitless chakra". Where did the chakra come from?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited amount of chakra, however, chakra replenishes so fast making it seemingly limitless. Similarly, body regeneration is also fast in Edo Tensei form.

Everyone naturally regenerates chakra. Edo Tensei people regenerate at a faster rate. We know chakra is limited, however, because the Mizukage was drained and tired after using his infinite explosion jutsu - `Joki Boi`

Comment: It could theoretically be limitless since they are undead. Complete chakra drain would normally cause a person to die.

Comment: Well . The deadly jutsus used by the reincarnated , require a certain large amount of chakra . The Steaming Danger Tyranny is one such jutsu . So if the reincarnated has to use a chakra taxing technique , he cant possibly do it with the assigned limited amount of chakra . (How  much chakra can Kabuto assign to each and every ET shinobi?)

Comment: @EroSennin The way I understand it is that every shinobi has their maximum chakra capacity C. That means their maximum amount of chakra stored should be C and shall never exceed C under normal circumstances. With Edo Tensei bodies, each shinobi is allowed to use up to C in any given technique and then they have speedy recovery rates that allows them to regenerate chakra at an inhuman rate. Kabuto can assign someone to have C amount or less.

Comment: @krikara Okay . But how does Kabuto get so much chakra to supply and assign to the reincarnated? He reincarnated all those shinobi and top of that , Madara. Or take Orochimaru . He reincarnated the previous 4 Hokage. I doubt if Orochi can assign half of Hashirama's reserves if he "assigns it by himself". So how is so much chakra being assinged/generated within the ET shinobi?

Comment: @EroSennin Similar to Pain's outer path, Kabuto only needs to chakra to initiate the resurrection. Once the souls are in the respective Edo Tensei bodies, those bodies regenerate on their own. That is why Kabuto can die and the resurrected people will still remain alive. Kabuto does not actually supply the chakra to each individual nor does he match their starting chakra. He only uses chakra to perform the jutsu.

Comment: Kabuto has no bearing on how much chakra a reincarnated individual has. He only reincarnates them. Once reincarnated, the person has the same reserves of chakra they had before their death, but it replenishes seemingly instantly after use, such that they can use their most powerful techniques over and over. They cannot, however, use a technique requiring more chakra than they were capable of producing when they were alive.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming to this late, but I've got an answer for this. There is an afterlife in the Naruto universe. Several techniques, including the Reaper Death Seal and Nagato's revival technique make mention of this. Based on the names and effects of those techniques, I believe that the Naruto universe has a single afterlife called Hell.

Based on the statements of revived Edo Tensei victims, Hell doesn't seem to be a bad place, so it's likely the name isn't representative of Christian hell. I believe that the other answers are right, the chakra comes from the accelerated unnatural regeneration that the revived possess.

However, I believe that the energy to fuel that regeneration comes from this Hell. It's a non-issue, as chakra doesn't really obey any laws of conservation of energy, but if it did, Hell could eventually run out of energy.