# Do Edo-Tensei ninja have infinite chakra?

Tags: naruto

It seems that people that were edo-tenseied were never out of chakra, would they have a limit on how much chakra they can use?

Comment: related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18730/6345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed one of the benefits of the [Edo Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation) Justu. Their chakra reserves are always refilled, allowing them to perform tasks and cast justus endlessly without having to worry about running out

> A second benefit is the limitless refilling of their diminished chakra reserves that the reincarnated individuals have access to; they can fight eternally and perform ordinarily physically demanding or chakra-intensive jutsu without issue, knowing their current reserves will infinitely refill

Comment: So they can use rinne rebirth many times?